# can't see asp.net gridview on page load

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview that won't show on page load.  The gridview is inside of some asp:Panels which are inside of an update panel.  I stepped through the code, so I know the gridview has rows of data.  If I move the gridview outside of the panels and update panels, then it will show up with data.  Does anybody know why it doesn't work as it sits below, inside of the panels and update panels?

```
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" EnableEventValidation="false" MasterPageFile="~/CTPublic.master" CodeFile="Tank.aspx.vb" Inherits="CargoTank_Internal_Tank" %>
```

```
<div style="padding-top:9px; width:100%; min-width:800px; " >
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpTank" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
                <ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender runat="server" BorderColor="#3260a0"   Corners="All" Radius="5" Color="#98B9C9"  TargetControlID="pnlTank" ID="ajRCEpnlTank" ></ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender>

         <asp:Panel runat="server" BackColor="#ecece7"  Width="95%"  ID="pnlTank" >

             <div >
            <div style="float:left; width:70%; background-color:#98B9C9; height:19px;">Tanks</div>
            <div style="float:right; width:30%; height:19px;background-color:#98B9C9; text-align:right">
                <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewTank" style="background:transparent; border:0px;" runat="server" Font-Underline="true"   size="1" Font-Bold=true text="Add New" /> 

             </div> 
            <div style="padding-top:19px;"></div>
            </div>   
            <div style="width:100%;">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6" class="tdheaderbar">Search Tanks
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>CT #</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCTNumber" ></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td>Serial #</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSerialNumber" MaxLength="17"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td>City</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCity"></asp:TextBox></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td>Capacity</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCapacity"></asp:TextBox></td>
                       <td>Unit #</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUnitNumber"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td>License State</td>
                        <td><asp:DropDownList EnableViewState="true" runat="server" ID="ddlState" DataSourceID="linqStates" 
                               Width="156px" DataTextField="StateText" DataValueField="StateID"></asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:LinqDataSource ID="linqStates" runat="server" 
                                ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext" TableName="States">
                            </asp:LinqDataSource>
                        </td>

                  </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td>Tank Type</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTankType"  Width="156px"
                                 ></asp:DropDownList>

                        </td> 
                        <td>Compartment</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCompartment"></asp:TextBox></td>
                         <td>License #</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLicenseNumber"></asp:TextBox></td>
                  </tr>
                      <tr>
                         <td>Manufacturer</td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlManufacturer"  
                                 ></asp:DropDownList>

                        </td> 


                       <td><asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkNoLogIn" Text="No Log In Associated" /></td>
                       <td></td> <td></td> 
                   </tr>
                   <tr><td>Company</td>
                        <td colspan="5"> <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCompany" ></asp:DropDownList></td>    
                 </tr>  
                 <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                    </td>
                    <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSearch" Text="Search" /></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

        </asp:Panel>
   </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>  
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
  <br />

      <div style="padding-top:9px; width:100%; " id="divTankDetail" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updTankDetail" runat="server"  >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:DropShadowExtender runat="server" ID="dsetank" TargetControlID="pnlTankDetail" TrackPosition="true" BehaviorID="pnlTankDetailHeader"></ajaxToolkit:DropShadowExtender>
        <ajaxToolkit:DragPanelExtender runat="server" ID="dpeTankDetail" TargetControlID="pnlTankDetail" DragHandleID="pnlTankDetailHeader"></ajaxToolkit:DragPanelExtender>
        <asp:Panel CssClass="TankpopupPosition" BackColor="LightBlue" Visible="false" runat="server" BorderColor="#3260a0" BorderWidth="2px"  Width="801px"  ID="pnlTankDetail" >
               <asp:Panel runat="server" BorderColor="#3260a0" BorderWidth="1px"  Width="800px"  ID="pnlTankDetailHeader">
             <div  >
            <div style="float:left; width:90%; background-color:#98B9C9; height:19px;">Tank Detail</div>
            <div style="float:right; width:10%; border-right-width:2px; border-width:1px; border-color:#3260a0; height:19px;background-color:#98B9C9; text-align:right">
                <asp:Button ID="btnClose" style="background:transparent; border:0px;" runat="server"   size="1" Font-Bold=true text="X" />&nbsp;
            </div> 

            <div style="padding-top:19px;"></div>
            </div>  
            </asp:Panel>
               <asp:Panel  runat="server"  Width="800px"  ID="pnlTankDetailBody">
                <div id="divTankDetailbody" runat="server" style="width:100%"  >
                 <br />
                 <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>CT #</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox TabIndex="10" runat="server" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2px" BackColor="Transparent" ID="txtCTNum" ReadOnly="true" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCTNumber" runat="server" Text="*"></asp:Label>&nbsp</td>
                        <td>Serial #</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox TabIndex="14" runat="server" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2px" ID="txtSeriaNum" MaxLength="17"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSerialNumber" runat="server" Text="*"></asp:Label>&nbsp</td>
                        <td>City</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" TabIndex="18" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2px" ID="txtOrignatedCity"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Capacity</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox TabIndex="11" runat="server" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2px" ID="txtTanktCapacity"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCapacity" runat="server" Text="*"></asp:Label>&nbsp</td>
                         <td>Compartment</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" TabIndex="15" ID="txtCompartment2" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2px"></asp:TextBox>
                      <asp:Label ID="lblCompartment" runat="server" Text="*"></asp:Label>&nbsp</td>

                                                    <td>License #</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" BorderStyle="Inset" TabIndex="19" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2px" ID="txtLicenseNum"></asp:TextBox></td>
                  </tr>
                     <tr>
                                                  <td>Tank Type</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" TabIndex="12" ID="ddlTankType2" Width="156px" 
                                 DataTextField="TankTypeName" 
                                DataValueField="TankTypeName"></asp:DropDownList><asp:Label ID="lblTankType" runat="server" Text="*"></asp:Label>&nbsp
                         </td> 
                        <td>Unit #</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" TabIndex="16" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="2px" ID="txtUnitNum"></asp:TextBox></td>

                        <td>License State</td>
                        <td> 
                            <asp:DropDownList EnableViewState="true" Width="156px" TabIndex="20"  runat="server" ID="ddlLicenseState" DataSourceID="linqStates" 
                                DataTextField="StateText" DataValueField="StateID"></asp:DropDownList>                                


                            <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext" TableName="States">
                            </asp:LinqDataSource>
                        </td>

                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                        <td>Manufacturer</td>
                        <td colspan="1">
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" TabIndex="13" ID="ddlManufacturer2"  
                               >
                                 </asp:DropDownList><asp:Label ID="lblManufacturer" runat="server" Text="*"></asp:Label>&nbsp
                         </td> 
                        <td>Company</td>
                        <td colspan="3"> <asp:DropDownList runat="server" TabIndex="17" ID="ddlCompany2" ></asp:DropDownList><asp:Label ID="lblCompany2" runat="server" Text="*"></asp:Label></td>      

                   </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" align="center"><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblChangeOwnership" Font-Size="Medium" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChangeOwnership" runat="server" Text="Changing ownership" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" align="center">
                        <br />
                     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" TabIndex="21" Text="Add" Width="60px" /> 
                     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" TabIndex="22" Text="Update" Width="60px" /> 
                     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnChangeOnwership" TabIndex="23" Text="Change" Width="60px" /> 
                     <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCancel" TabIndex="24" Text="Cancel" Width="60px"  />
                     <br /><br />
                        <asp:GridView ID="grdTanks" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="Transparent" GridLines="None" 
                            PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageSize="10" 
                            RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" Width="100%">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternateItemStyle" />
                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" />
                            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
                            <RowStyle CssClass="itemStyle" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CargoTankID" HeaderText="CT #" InsertVisible="False" 
                                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CargoTankID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyID" HeaderText="CompanyID" 
                                    SortExpression="CompanyID" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="OriginatedCity" HeaderText="OriginatedCity" 
                                    SortExpression="OriginatedCity" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="LicenseNumber" HeaderText="LicenseNumber" 
                                    SortExpression="LicenseNumber" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="LicenseState" HeaderText="LicenseState" 
                                    SortExpression="LicenseState" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitNumber" HeaderText="Unit Number" 
                                    SortExpression="UnitNumber" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#DisplayCompanyName(Eval("CompanyID"))%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="SerialNumber" HeaderText="Serial Number" 
                                    SortExpression="SerialNumber" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Capacity" HeaderText="Capacity" 
                                    SortExpression="Capacity" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Manufacturer">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#DisplayManufacturer(Eval("ManufacturerID"))%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TankType" HeaderText="Tank Type" 
                                    SortExpression="TankType" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Compartment" HeaderText="Compartment" 
                                    SortExpression="Compartment" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="DecalID" HeaderText="DecalID" 
                                    SortExpression="DecalID" Visible="false" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Decal Status">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <%#DisplayTestLink(Eval("CargoTankID"))%>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                     </td>

                  </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
   </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" EventName="Click" />

    </Triggers>  
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        If (Me.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) Then
            Dim db As DataClassesDataContext = New DataClassesDataContext()

            Dim tanks = From t In db.CT_Tanks _
                        Select t

            Me.grdTanks.DataSource = tanks
            Me.grdTanks.DataBind()

            Dim tanktype = (From t In db.CT_TankTypes _
                            Select t).ToList

            ddlTankType.DataSource = tanktype
            ddlTankType.DataTextField = "TankTypeName"
            ddlTankType.DataValueField = "TankTypeName"
            ddlTankType.DataBind()
            ddlTankType.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select a Type --")
            ddlTankType2.DataSource = tanktype
            ddlTankType2.DataTextField = "TankTypeName"
            ddlTankType2.DataValueField = "TankTypeName"
            ddlTankType2.DataBind()
            ddlTankType2.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select a Type --")

            Dim manufacturer = (From m In db.CT_Manufacturers _
                               Select m).ToList

            ddlManufacturer.DataSource = manufacturer
            ddlManufacturer.DataTextField = "ManufacturerName"
            ddlManufacturer.DataValueField = "ManufacturerID"
            ddlManufacturer.DataBind()
            ddlManufacturer.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select a Manufacturer --")

            ddlManufacturer2.DataSource = manufacturer
            ddlManufacturer2.DataTextField = "ManufacturerName"
            ddlManufacturer2.DataValueField = "ManufacturerID"
            ddlManufacturer2.DataBind()
            ddlManufacturer2.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select a Manufacturer --")

            Dim companies = (From c In db.CT_Companies _
                             Where c.IsOwner = True _
                             Select c Order By c.CompanyName Ascending).ToList

            ddlCompany.DataSource = companies
            ddlCompany.DataTextField = "CompanyName"
            ddlCompany.DataValueField = "CompanyID"
            ddlCompany.DataBind()
            ddlCompany.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select a Company --")

            ddlCompany2.DataSource = companies
            ddlCompany2.DataTextField = "CompanyName"
            ddlCompany2.DataValueField = "CompanyID"
            ddlCompany2.DataBind()
            ddlCompany2.Items.Insert(0, "-- Select a Company --")

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: have you bind the datasource ?

Comment: yes.  As I stated above, I made sure the gridview has data, and if I move the gridview outside of all the panels and update panels, then it works fine, it shows up with data.  If I keep it inside of the panels, it doesn't show up......

Comment: have you added ScriptManager ??

Comment: it's on the master page, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but adding this may help you out

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
```

Comment: I already had a scriptmanager on the master page, I added the enablePartialRendering=true, but that didn't work.....

Comment: @user1202606 : post your serverside code ie (binding gridview).

Comment: I just posted it above.  I know it's populating the grid, as I originally stated, if I move the gridview outside of the panels and update panels, it shows up, populated.  If I step through the code, I can see it has data, it just won't show up while in the panels and update panels.

Comment: @user1202606:  also bind gridview   in else part of notpostback ?

Comment: Maybe the update panel isn't being triggered.. after you update your grid.

Comment: it appears to look for a file called extendercontrolbase.cs, which appears to be part of the ajaxtoolkit.  Do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

your update panel doesn't seem to be triggered after you databind the gridview

try:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updTankDetail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
```

then in your code behind put

```
updTankDetail.Update()
```

Comment: that didn't work, it looks like it's looking for a file called extendercontrolbase.cs.  Probably part of the ajaxcontroltookit....

Comment: if your getting that error, you probably have some missing ajax files. May be a good thing to try and re-install ajax.

Comment: I deleted the ajax dll and pdb and downloaded and installed new ones in the bin, that didn't work.  Is there anything else I should do besides that?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this  place my gridview inside update panel under panel and its works..

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnContainer" runat="server">
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:GridView ID="gvempgrade" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        onrowcancelingedit="gvempgrade_RowCancelingEdit" 
        onrowediting="gvempgrade_RowEditing" 
        onrowupdating="gvempgrade_RowUpdating" ShowFooter="True" 
        onrowcommand="gvempgrade_RowCommand" 
        onrowdeleting="gvempgrade_RowDeleting">
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#A86E07" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#603813" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resources, SrNo %>" ItemStyle-CssClass="srcenteralg" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-Width="55" >
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblid" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id_grd") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resources, Grade %>"  >
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblgrade" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("grade_grd") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtempgrade" Width="55" CssClass="alphabetsOnlynospace" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("grade_grd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate >
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfempgrade" CssClass="alphabetsOnlynospace" runat="server" Width="55"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resources, Description %>" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbldiscription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("description_grd") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtempdescription" CssClass="alphabetsOnly" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("description_grd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfempdescription" CssClass="alphabetsOnly" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resources, Maxctc %>" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
               <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblmaxctc" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("max_ctc_grd") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtmaxctc" CssClass="numbersOnly" MaxLength="10" Width="100" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("max_ctc_grd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfmaxctc" CssClass="numbersOnly" MaxLength="10" Width="100" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resources, Minctc %>"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
               <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblminctc" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("min_ctc_grd") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtminctc" MaxLength="10" CssClass="numbersOnly"  Width="100" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("min_ctc_grd") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfminctc" MaxLength="10" CssClass="numbersOnly" Width="100" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>

            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Width="190px" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button  ID="btnedit" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="btngradiant" 
                        CommandName="Edit" Text="<%$ Resources:Resources, Edit %>"></asp:Button >
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button  ID="btnupdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="btngradiant"
                        CommandName="Update" Text="Update" OnClientClick="return updatevalidation();" ></asp:Button >
                    &nbsp;<asp:Button  ID="btncancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="btngradiant"
                        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:Button >
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate >

                    <asp:Button ID="btninsert" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resources, Add %>" CommandName="Add"   CssClass="btngradiant" OnClientClick="return validation();" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="btngradiant" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");'
                            CommandName="Delete" Text="<%$ Resources:Resources, Delete %>"></asp:Button>
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#A86E07" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A86E07" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#d9d9d9" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#A86E07" />
    </asp:GridView>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
On pageLoad()

 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dtfetch = emp.Fetchreord();
            gvempgrade.DataSource = dtfetch;
            gvempgrade.DataBind();
        }
```

**Note:** As you getting error related to `extendercontrolbase.cs`  that mean dll missing, try to comment all Extender controls and see whether it works

Answer (score 0):

The title: can't see asp.net gridview on page load
I see in code you use a panel with `id="ID="pnlTankDetail""` and the panel `ID="pnlTankDetail"` has property Visible="False"`so the gridview`grdTanks`can't show in page load. You should change to`Visible="true`to see gridview. And` `i think the`div`tag not have property`runnat="server"`.Hope this help.